# ошибки нету но при нажатии на кнопку "Промокод" он не выводиться, не могу понять почему

Tags: python, telebot

код:

```
import telebot
import config
import random
import sqlite3 as sql
from telebot import types

con = sql.connect("data.db", check_same_thread=False)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(id INT)")

bot = telebot.TeleBot('my_token')

chan_id = -1002007922846
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    
    markupp = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Подписаться", url="https://t.me/+ld7jowsQLxwxYjA6", callback_data='subscribe')
    item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Проверить", callback_data='check')

    markupp.add(item1, item2)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Добро пожаловать, " + message.from_user.first_name +"!"
     "\nДля использования бота - подпишись на наш канал", parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markupp)
    
    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
    def c_listener(call):
        
        if call.data == "check":
            x = bot.get_chat_member(chan_id, call.message.chat.id)
            if x.status == "member" or x.status == "creator" or x.status == "administrator":
                #bot.send_photo(id, open('start.jpg'))

                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
                item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Регистрация", url="https://1wgtqa.life/casino/list?open=register#siml", callback_data='next')
                item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Получить сигнал", callback_data="signal")
                item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Промокод", callback_data='promo')
                markup.add(item1, item2, item3)

                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,"""Добро пожаловать в EPLMINESBOT!

            Mines - это гэмблинг игра в букмекерской конторе 1win, которая основывается на классическом “Сапёре”.
            Ваша цель - открывать безопасные ячейки и не попадаться в ловушки.

            Шанс на победу ≈ 80%.""", parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)
                cur.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES(?)", (call.message.chat.id, ))
                con.commit()
            else:
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Вы не подписались!", reply_markup=markupp)

    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
    def lalala(call):
        if call.data == 'promo':

            markup = types.InlineKeyboardButton(row_width=2)
            item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Регистрация", url="https://1wgtqa.life/casino/list?open=register#siml", callback_data='next')
            item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Получить сигнал", callback_data="signal")
            item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("<<Назад", callback_data='check')
            markup.add(item1, item2, item3)
            mess = ' ПРОМОКОД - "EPLTAKE500"'
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, mess, reply_markup=markup)
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я не знаю что ответить ')
    


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Шанс на победу: долг под 16% минимум